# How change the back button to a custom image in Swift2

Tags: ios, image, swift, swift2, viewcontroller

#### Hi,

I'm trying to figure out how to change the back button to a *custom image* on all ViewControllers. I read though a few questions regarding to this solution, but it was mostly outdated.
I want to change < Back to a stock image I have

[image]

I was able to disable to hide the back but that's not my goal my goal is to change the default image to a custom one, I added the custom image to the *images.xcassets* and that didn't work also I tried to set the **System Item** to **Custom** and under **Bar Item** I selected my image which is image.png, but still didn't work, can someone help me approach this  solution? Thanks.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "images")!
        
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.image = image
        
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
//        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
//        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing that you can create your own custom button and assign it to leftBarButtonItem. Try this out

```
var backBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "images")!
backBtn.image = image
//set other properties for your button
//set traget and action
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
```

You can just pop the current view controller in action of the back button.

Comment: the back button appears as a big blue square not my image, I can click it and it will do a clicking motion but it won't go back.

Comment: @Francesc  add action like this
In ViewDidLoad paste this

 let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")!
    backBtn.image = image
    backBtn.action = #selector(popSelf)
    backBtn.target = self
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn

create following function, 

 func popSelf() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        // do your stuff if you needed
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in AppDelegate

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: name), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

This will set back button through out the app